# Is there any way to call and use auth0 sdk libraries in chrome extension mv3 background.js file

Tags: auth0, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, auth0-lock

Trying convert chrome extension v2 to v3 . Since background.js is a service worker now  ,i'm not able to use auth0-spa libraries in it. Is there any workaround to use auth0/auth0-spa libraries in background.js . Any help would be much appreciated